# How to use postgres pgcrypto with python?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, authentication, pgcrypto

I'm new to postgres and making an command line password manager using python. I want to hash my master password using python and store it into database. I used pgcrypto in psql shell and it worked but can't figure out how to use it with python. A little help from anyone can get my done.

Comment: Why not use the Python [crypto](https://docs.python.org/3/library/crypto.html) module? If you insist on using `pgcrypto` then you will need to connect to the database use one of its functions(via a query) either return the encrypted value  or `INSERT/UPDATE` the desired record with it.

Comment: If you want to do the hashing in python, then you shouldn't use pgcrypto in the first place, as that is not python.

Comment: okay thanks for your respond. If it works i well let you know.